# Apache poi circular references?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have created a sheet for a shop using apache poi. I have 3 columns

```
    Quantity | Price | Sub-Total
```

and I added a formula for all the cells of the `Price` column and the  `Sub-Total` column. `Sub-Total = Quantity * Price`, `Price = Sub-Total/Quantity`.

```java
        XSSFCell cell01 = row0.createCell(1);
        cell01.setCellFormula("QUOTIENT(A1:C1)");

        XSSFCell cell02 = row0.createCell(2);
        cell02.setCellFormula("PRODUCT(A1:B1)");
```

But it seem doesn't work. And show the warning: `circular references` 
How I fix the circular references

Comment: You have to start the calculation from a fixed value. How would you manually fill in a row with the given info? It's logically impossible currently.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I had  init the Quantity and user just enter Price or Sub-Total